# Django foreign key count filter

Tags: python, sql, django

I have the following two models:

```
Class Foo(models.model):
    param1 = ...
    param2 = ...
    ...
    paramN = ...

Class Bar(models.model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    ...
    ...
```

**GOAL:** Compute a QuerySet of all instances of Foo such that more than 1 Bar instance is connected to it

I have been looking for a solution and this seems to work for everybody else

```
Foo.objects.annotate(num_bar=Count('bar')).filter(num_bar__gt=1)
```

This gave me a `FieldError` saying that `'bar'` was not a possible field for `Foo`, I then tried `'bar_set'` and also got the same error

Is there a chance I am implementing them wrong, or because they are old they are depreciated now? Any help would be appreciated!

## traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ryan/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ryan/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 794, in annotate
    obj.query.add_annotation(annotation, alias, is_summary=False)
  File "/home/ryan/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 982, in add_annotation
    summarize=is_summary)
  File "/home/ryan/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/aggregates.py", line 20, in resolve_expression
    c = super(Aggregate, self).resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize)
  File "/home/ryan/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 491, in resolve_expression
    c.source_expressions[pos] = arg.resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize, for_save)
  File "/home/ryan/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 448, in resolve_expression
    return query.resolve_ref(self.name, allow_joins, reuse, summarize)
  File "/home/ryan/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1532, in resolve_ref
    self.get_initial_alias(), reuse)
  File "/home/ryan/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1471, in setup_joins
    names, opts, allow_many, fail_on_missing=True)
  File "/home/ryan/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1396, in names_to_path
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'bar' into field. Choices are: param1, param2, param3, ..., paramN
```

## version

my django version is 1.8.3

Comment: The first one should definitely work. You should probably post your real models and the code you used. You're using the second one wrong, but I won't correct it because `extra` is deprecated and this is definitely better done via `annotate`.

Comment: I saw you correct your model, then your first approach should work. Can you try to print the raw query by doing `print Foo.objects.annotate(num_bar=Count('bar')).filter(num_bar__gt=1).query` and see if it comes up something. I suspect that you did something in your model that prevent the ORM from working properly.

Comment: @ShangWang running the code you gave above gives me the identical `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'bar' into field`

Comment: @DanielRoseman due to confidentiality I cannot post the full models, is there any specific area of the model you would like to see? I figured the foreign key is the only relevant part as that is the only aspect of the models I use. The line of code I tried is identical to what was posted but with the names of the models changed.

Comment: Are they in the same app? If not are both apps included in INSTALLED_APPS? In the shell, if you do `f = Foo.objects.first()` then `f.bar_set.all()`, what do you get?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, both apps are in installed apps and the same application. They are both used in many other aspects of projects and have not had any individual problems. I can even do `Foo.objects.get(pk=some_id).bar_set.all()`, which returns a list with `Bar` objects. Problem is I need to look at the ones with more than one object only and most have exactly one object.

Comment: What Django version are you using? And can you show the full traceback? I'm not sure I can do much else to help you if you can't show the real models. All I can say is that this syntax *does* work.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have added the full traceback in a way that should help and specified the version. The specifics of the model that I can say is that there are about 20 fields in both `Foo` and `Bar`. Some FK, M2M, Text, Char, Decimal, Boolean, DateTime, and JSON with no custom functions. But this should not be relevant to my knowledge. If there is something you need to know specifically, I can see what I can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying a lot, this was a solution that worked:

```
Bar.objects.values("foo_id").annotate(Count("foo_id")).filter(pk__count__gt=1)
```

Not exactly sure why this worked and the other didn't, but it essentially just gets the count of `Bar` objects with the same `foo_id` and makes sure there is more than 1.

If somebody would like to explain a potential reason why this works and the other did not, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue by import mistake. This is solution for my use case

```
# from django.db.models.sql.aggregates import Count  # wrong import
from django.db.models import Count   # correct one
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for this error, I'll try to tell the probable causes:

1. Recently upgrading your django version may cause the problem, clear
   migrations, rerun.
2. Moving from local server to production server can cause this problem
   sometimes.
3. Your app name can cause the problem, if it starts with "__".
4. Try other simpler queries, if they work, try to change the query so
   that you don't use the `num_model`.
5. also check if you can get the count of them ( the dirty way :) ):

   `for foo in Foo.objects.all():
       if foo.bar_set.count() < 2:
           #do sth like : foo.bar_set.get() or temp = temp + 1`

as of your short description of model (not your main code), cannot find other causes. Your query should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately 1-4 are not a problem and the `Foo` DB table has over 60 million entries, so 5 is not something that I should do. And I cannot even really sample for 5 as there are only a small subset where `foo.bar_set.count()` will be greater than 1